# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'bsmn'

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

i have import the db to my php admin and the problem still :

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'bsmn' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bsmn\connection.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bsmn\connection.php(8): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bsmn') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\bsmn\index.php(4): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bsmn\connection.php on line 8
> this is the line 8 > if(!$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname))
> this file connection.php

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "bsmn";
if(!$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname))
{

    die("failed to connect!");
}
```

Comment: You don't have a database named `bsmn`, apparently

Comment: You are trying to connect to non existent database named 'bsmn'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Means you have no database named bsmn, if you use phpmyadmin find the databases on the left and be sure that this matches what you have in your code above.

```
$dbname = "bsmn"; //This is looking for a database of the same name
```

Navigate to PhpMyadmin and check the left side like the below image, there you will see what databases you can connect to, if "bsmn" is not in the list, it doesnt exist.

Maybe you are looking for a table called "bsmn" but this would be in a database and you will need that database name instead.

[image]

Comment: but i have in the file htdocs the file bsmn who contain the db

Comment: `bsmn` wouldn't be a file, it would be in the database itself. When you bring up phpmyadmin, what databases does it show?

Comment: @dr_wayn - What "file" are you referring to and what do you mean "contain the db"? Your MySQL server (database server, which has nothing to do with your files in your htdocs) simply don't seem to have a database with the name you're trying to use.

Comment: hey the problem is solved finally i have added the db table in the wrong admin so to solve the problem i got to xampp and i clicked in the my sql admin and i Added the table in my sql admin thank you for your answer